# How to download multiple HTML pages to dropbox with apify using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropbox, apify

I'm using Apify to crawl about a hundred pages, and I wish to download the HTML files of all the pages I visit into a dropbox folder. How do I specify this in my jQuery Ajax code?

Sorry in advance, I am quite new to Javascript and everything web-related.

I've tried to follow these tutorials already: https://forum.apify.com/t/data-download-from-within-crawler/48 and https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-save_url, however, I am only able to download the HTML file of the second page I visit. I know that my crawler works perfectly fine and visits all the sites it needs to, as I am getting the results I need from these pages, so the problem seems to be that I am not specifying that I want to download all the HTML files. How do I do this?

(In my actual code I have written in the correct Oath-token, I just don't want it to be available online for everyone to see)

```
var html = $('html').html();

var url = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload";

$.ajax({  
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/octet-stream",
    headers: {  
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + 'My Oath-token',
        "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{\"mode\":\"add\",\"path\":\"/a.txt\"}",
        },  
    type: 'POST',
    data: html,
    autoRename: true,
    max_results: 1000
});
```

What I am getting out of this is one file saved as a.txt in my dropbox, which is what I wanted, only that this file only includes one HTML file, not a file including all the files my crawler had visited.

This code is the first thing my crawler meets for every new page it visits.

Comment: It looks like you keep overwriting the file `a.txt`

Comment: Oh oops, that makes a lot of sense. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: You're using a loop, so you should have an index variable of some kind? Just add that to the filename, like `a001.txt`, `a002.txt` and so on.